# rails 4 - undefined method `valid?'

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join, where-clause

I recently upgraded my rails to Rails 4

This query used to work :

```
@user = User.joins(:cars).where('cars.color' => "blue")
```

But now I got this error message:

> undefined method `valid?' for #<
>   User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000100bbc668 >

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query `User.joins(:cars).where('cars.color' => "blue")` returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` instance. Check [docs here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where).

If you really want to operate over an instance (of User class), you must take a user from that collection, for example:

```
@user = User.joins(:cars).where('cars.color' => "blue").first
```

An `ActiveRecord::Relation` doesn't respond to methods like: .save, .update_attributes